# How to tag or add metadata to a video file with GStreamer?

Tags: file, video, metadata, gstreamer, mp4

I would like to add metadatas to an MP4 video file with GStreamer:

1. How to do it while recording the file?
2. How to do it when the file is already recorded?
3. Is that possible to check these modifications with GStreamer?

---

For example, with FFmpeg, I can add a title to my video with this command line:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -metadata title="my title" out.mp4`

And then, I check the result with mediainfo:

```
mediainfo out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it with a debug plugin: taginject

For example, in order to tag a file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! taginject tags="title=\"MyTitle\",artist=\"MyArtist\"" ! mp4mux ! filesink location=tagged_file.mp4
```

If you want to check it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -t filesrc location=tagged_file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! fakesink
```

Comment: I can set many fields this way, but artist and title remain unchanged