# GStreamer write tags

Tags: gstreamer

im currently developing a media application which I want to be able to edit tags of a audio/video file using GStreamer 1.0

I know this can be achieved using the function `gst_tag_list_merge` , but this function expects an argument of type `GstTagList` . The only way I know of getting a `GstTagList` from a pipeline is adding a bus watch and then listen to the `GST_MESSAGE_TAG` event. But since this is fired multiple times in a stream (once for each tag there is) I assume the `GstTagList` I can get from this is not the complete one. So, how can I get a taglist from my stream which I can use to edit it and save back to the stream to update the tags?

I know this question is very specific im sorry for that :(

regards, NiAypa

Comment: Take a look at the question I previously had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470961/how-to-tag-or-add-metadata-to-a-video-file-with-gstreamer Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have stumbled upon taginject before it seems nice but I cannot find any API that it uses so I could call it in my C/C++ code, the way it is suggested in your question seems to require the use of a system() call which I would like to avoid due to cross-platform (and security) issues :/ Do you know if there is any way to get direct access to the taginject plugin?

Comment: In your C code, you can set the taginject element (named taginject0) property "tags" string like this: `g_object_set (taginject0, "tags", string, NULL);`

Comment: oh ver y nice thank you :)